# Установить приложение сразу после компиляции

Tags: установка, android, android-studio

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы после сборки приложения в android studio приложение сразу же устанавливалось на мое устройство, без проводов, через wi-fi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала нужно порутованное устройство. Потом устанавливаете приложение вида [wifiadb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=uk) (или гуглите по adb air и получаете пачку приложений).

Потом только нужно в консоли написать `adb connect ip:port` (айпи и порт телефона) и все будет работать, как будто по кабелю.